# First argument of concat doesn't seem to be completing

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to run `concat` on two observables, however, the second observable in the `concat` is not running and I am not sure why. The only thing that happens is `done` from the first observable prints out. I have created a simplified version of my code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-jkx7c3?file=index.ts).

Here is the start of the script, it runs the first observable in the concat but not the second, and the completion message never executes:

```js
function refresh() {
  const files = new Files();
  const deleteExisting = files.deleteExisting();
  const saveFiles = files.query().pipe(tap((i) => console.log(i)));

  concat(deleteExisting, saveFiles).subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log('Concat done!'),
  });
}

refresh();
```

Next I have a class that queries the database and streams the files one-by-one it checks if the file is on the os if not it adds it to the deletion list (to be deleted later). Once this finished `done` is printed out to the console which is expected.

```js
export class Files extends DB {
  deleteExisting() {
    const toDelete: string[] = [];
    return this.stream().pipe(
      mergeMap((file) =>
        from(this.pathExists(file)).pipe(map((i) => [file, i]))
      ),
      tap<[string, boolean]>(
        ([file, exists]) => exists === false && toDelete.push(file)
      ),
      toArray(),
      map(() => toDelete.length),
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('done');
      })
    );
  }

  // The real code does `fs.pathExists()` from fs-extra which returns a promise
  pathExists(path: string) {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

Here we have a fake database class, the actual data comes from sqlite.

- The `stream()` method returns results one-by-one (this is done by the sqlite module) and I relay that to the subject.
- The `query()` method returns results as an array, and I relay that to the subject.

```js
export class DB {
  private results1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  private results2 = [1, 2, 3];

  stream() {
    const sub = new Subject<string | number>();
    // Simulate getting rows one-by-one from the db
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Runs a db call sqlite supports an `each` function which basically does this:
      this.results1.forEach((row) => sub.next(row));
      // Once each finishes a callback is called returning the number of results
      // This line is simulating that
      sub.next(this.results1.length);
    });
    return sub
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(takeWhile<string>((i) => typeof i === 'string'));
  }

  query() {
    const sub = new Subject<number[]>();
    // Simulate a callback that returns all results from database as an array
    setTimeout(() => sub.next(this.results2), 100);
    return sub.asObservable().pipe(take(1));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `query()` method.

When subscribing to a plain `Subject`, you will only receive the notifications emitted **after** the moment of the subscription. And in your case your just emitting once in the subject and is way before subscription.

To test it you could use the `of` operator to return the values of `results2`

```
query() {
   return of(this.results2);
}
```

And you'll see the array gets printed.

Cheers

Comment: Oops, sorry my mistake, that should be a `setTimeout`, which I did update, however, it still produces the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I was running the query before calling `concat` making it execute too soon. Wrapping the query within an Observable so it runs when concat calls it instead of right away fixes the issue:

```js
  const saveFiles = new Observable((sub) => {
    files.query().subscribe((i) => sub.next(i));
  }).pipe(tap((i) => console.log(i)));
```

`defer` also seems to work as well.

```
  const saveFiles = defer(() => files.query())
    .pipe(tap((i) => console.log(i)))
```